# Centering screenshots on github

Tags: image, github, jupyter-notebook, formatting

I have inserted an image on jupyter a notebook using:

`![tree%20diagram-3.png](attachment:tree%20diagram-3.png)`

In the notebook the image is centered:

[Centered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAVud.png)

While in github it is aligned to the left:

[Image in github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWBNn.png)

It is possible to center the image in github?

Comment: GitHub's rendering is only meant for quick previews of notebooks for developers. It doesn't offer a lot of the features and abilities offered by the solution offered by the Jupyter developers, [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/), does for sharing 'static' views of notebooks. Go to that link and put in the URL of your notebook and you'll get a nice rendering for sharing with non-developers. Hopefully your image will be centered as in the original notebook. Most Jupyter users learned this quickly early on when GitHub used to only try rendering notebooks under 100kb in size.

Comment: Note that I put 'static' in parentheses because nbviewer will actually allow javascript interactive features, such as Plotly and pre-rendered animations. And so they aren't 100% static. Better scrolling support and not cutting off long lines of code from view are just some of the other features that make nbviewer better. The URL that nbviewer makes from the URL of the notebook's `.ipynb` json online at GitHub is based on a pattern and so once you learn the pattern you can share URLs to nbviewer renderings of your notebooks hosted at GitHub without even needing to enter the URL in the form.